# ul on hover show items not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a menu, where on intial state the menu will be hidde and when the user hover over it shoud show the hidden menu.

Code

```
<div class="leftPanel">
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a>User</a>

            <ul class='hiddenMenu'>
                <li><a>Add User</a>
                </li>
                <li><a>Update User</a>
                </li>
                <li><a>Delete User</a>
                </li>
                <li><a>Ban User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>View Service Request</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>About us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Log out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul .hiddenMenu {
 display: none;
}

ul .hiddenMenu:hover{
 display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sas/wqzh8x9x/)

It doesn't shows the menu on hovering. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you're trying to show an element that's already hidden, so you can't really hover over it.

Comment: Have you tried changing `ul .hiddenMenu:hover { display: block; }` to `ul li a:hover ~ .hiddenMenu { display: block; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not hovering the hidden menu item; you're hovering the li parent of it. You also have a space between `ul` and `.hiddenMenu`, which is incorrect, since `.hiddenMenu` IS your ul's class name. Change it to:

```css
#cssmenu li:hover .hiddenMenu {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzh8x9x/3/)

I ultimately removed the `ul` preceeding `.hiddenMenu`, since it was unneeded specificity, which (marginally) slows down the browser's interpretation of the CSS.

Comment: Deleting my answer. This is cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:hover ul.hiddenMenu{
 display: block;
}
```